# Search whole dataframe for empty cells except specific columns - how to write condensed code to do this?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm writing code that data cleans my original dataframe and then spits out a dataframe of all the rows with errors. This line of code currently finds empty cells in the column 'RaceId'. I have 40 other columns and I would like to find empty cells in all of them apart from 'InRun' and 'Flucs'. How do I create a line of code that does this so I don't have to write out 40 lines of code?

My code:

```
df2[(df2['RaceId'] == '']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove rows that have empty string in all the specified columns, pass `all` to `agg`

```
df[your_col_list].apply(lambda x: x == '').agg(all, axis=1)
```

Otherwise, pass `any` to `agg`.

Comment: so would it be df['InRun','Flucs'].apply(lambda x: x == '').agg(all, axis=1)?

Comment: Multiple columns need to be passed as a list, so: `df[['InRun','Flucs']].apply(lambda x: x == '').agg(all, axis=1)`